# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small in Concatenation operator ||

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a string with 250,000 characters and I want copy that value to `clob` type. I chunked to 8 chunk (varchar2 type), Then I want convert to clob format but I get this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

My code:

```
declare   vstr_part1 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length '  
vstr_part2 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part3 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part4 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part5 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part6 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part7 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part8 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length '
vClobVal   clob;
vClobVal :=  vstr_part1 ||  vstr_part2 ||  vstr_part3 ||vstr_part4 || vstr_part5||  vstr_part6 ||vstr_part7 ||vstr_part8 ;
```

When I use just two chunk that worked but more than 2 chunk I get the same error.

What is my mistake?

Comment: you need to use a CLOB and DBMS_LOB to append.

Comment: @OldProgrammer   please give me code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error in your code is to convert the varchar2 to CLOB first using TO_CLOB function and then you can concat them -

```
declare   vstr_part1 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length '  
vstr_part2 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part3 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part4 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part5 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part6 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part7 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length ' 
vstr_part8 varchar2(32767) := ' long string with  32,670  length '
vClobVal   clob;
BEGIN
vClobVal :=  TO_CLOB(vstr_part1) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part2) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part3)  || TO_CLOB(vstr_part4) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part5) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part6) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part7) || TO_CLOB(vstr_part8);
END;
/
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Y4oxENR)

Comment: Plain **wrong**. In SQL, VARCHAR2 *was* limited to 4000 bytes; in e.g. Oracle 23c, if MAX_STRING_SIZE initialization parameter is set to EXTENDED, it supports 32767 bytes. Not to mention PL/SQL (which is being discussed here), where VARCHAR2 variables support 32767 bytes. Comments don't support formatting, but copy/paste this piece of code and see for yourself. `declare
  l_str varchar2(10000);
begin
  l_str := lpad('x', 9000, 'x');
  dbms_output.put_line(length(l_str));
end;
/`

Comment: varchar2 support 32676 `https://dbfiddle.uk/zuBPoKdx`

Comment: @Littlefoot, Updated my code with the demo. But still huge thanks for your comment.